# Substitute for chickpeas in Thailand

Tags: substitutions

I can't find chickpeas. What would you recommend instead when making falafel?

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but other names for chickpeas include garbanzos, ceci, or chana dal. Depending what kind of international markets are available to you, they might use one of these names instead of chickpeas.

Comment: Besan flour or Gram flour (both chickpeas) are probably too fine for falafel. Fresh cooked broad beans or Fava beans might work. https://www.google.com/search?q=broad+beans&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: @WayfaringStranger : cooked?  I thought that felafel was made from ground uncooked beans (either fresh or dried & soaked).  See http://www.telegraph.co.uk/foodanddrink/recipes/10146437/Broad-bean-falafel-sandwich-with-tahinisauce.html

Comment: @Joe Tinned (or canned) chickpeas are cooked. As the first comment in your link implies, it is possible to overcook the things. Soaking for a few days *should* work too, but I've always been too impatient for that.

Answer (score 3):

I have personally made felafel with split peas (both green and yellow) as well as chickpeas and several other types of bean. I have not tried red beans as I don't like them. While not exactly the same as chickpea, the split pea felafel were felafel, not something unrecognizable as felafel, though the green ones were quite green ;-)

I don't use canned beans for felafel, I use soaked dried beans.

Answer (score 1):

Look for goobers.   Same thing. Normally in can goods.  Bigger stores. Ram brand Garbanozos bean is what I buy. Red  can. With photo of chick peas on it. Normaly near Ram pork & beans in store.

Comment: I haven't heard the term 'goober' in many years.  (possibly 30 yrs ago, when I lived in Alabama).  But it always referred to peanuts.

Comment: In the Philippines were I live. There are hold over words from WW2 & Military slang that don't mean the same as in America. In America you are right.  In Thailand same but more British in slang. So word do change some.

Answer (score 1):

Split huskless mung beans can be used.

Comment: These should be very easy to find in Thailand as well. Best suggestion in my opinion